# Knockout "If viewModel property contains 'some text'"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I was relying on the answer here [How to check contain in knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876740/how-to-check-contain-in-knockout) but it seems to be for an outdated version of Knockout. I'm trying to do something like:

```
<li>
   <span data-bind="text: Subject"></span>
   <!-- ko if: Subject.contains('Important') -->
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
   <!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

Where the fontawesome icon is appended to the ko Subject text if that Subject text contains the word 'Important'. This however does not work ('contains' is not a function), and I am struggling to find an "up-to-date" solution.

Comment: need `()` also better way to check a substring  => `<!-- ko if: Subject().indexOf('Important') !== -1 -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
<li>
   <span data-bind="text: Subject"></span>
   <!-- ko if: Subject().indexOf('Important') !== -1 -->
   <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
   <!-- /ko -->
</li>
```

And it works! Thanks, Matt.kaaj. I think Roy's way is the way to go if this is something I'm doing in multiple places, but since I'm only checking the string for a keyword once in the site, I went with the straightforward inline solution. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

If you want there to be a `contains` method for observables, you can [add it as a custom function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html). Or you could add it just to `vm.Subject`, or you could inline it as Matt suggested.

```js
ko.observable.fn.contains = function (str) {
  return this().indexOf(str) > -1;
};

vm = {
  Subject: ko.observable('This is Important')
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(() => vm.Subject('This is not'), 1500);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="text: Subject"></span>
<!-- ko if: Subject.contains('Important') -->
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
<!-- /ko -->
```